# Prevent browser jump to top page when submit the form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to prevent the page jumping to top when the user submits the form. There are many people suggesting `return false`. However, it also prevents the form to be submitted too.

I was wondering if anyone could help me about it.

```
**JQuery**

$('#submit').click(function(){ //doesn't work
    return false;
})

$('form').submit(function(){  //doesn't work either
    return false;       
})



**Html**
<form...>
<input>...
<input>...
<input>...

<input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit'>

</form>
```

Comment: Is the form submitting back to the same page?

Comment: Do you want ajax-like functionality?

Comment: @nnnnnn no, the form will submit to another page, but I have form validation error messages that pop if the form fails, The page will jump to top when the error messages pop. I want the page stay where it is. Thanks.

Comment: @Simon, as long as there are no other way, I would try your way. Thanks.

Comment: Jerry, try updating your question and example code more specific to your problem concerning error validation. If you're reloading the page, the 'jump' is inevitable. I would take @Simon's advice on this one and go AJAX

Comment: Are the validation error messages that you're talking about all done in JavaScript, or are they coming back from the server? (If all in JS then you'd need to return false when there's an error.)

Comment: @nnnnnn The error messages were populated by codeigniter engine. It seems to me now that codeigniter reloaded the page after I submitted the form and populated the error messages. I guess there is no way to prevent it. :(

Comment: @Kyle yes. I guess there is nothing I can do except using Simon's advises since it reloads the page. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit the form you are effectively loading a new page. Returning false in the `submit` handler simply tells the browser not to bubble the event and not perform the default event, which in this case is submiting the form, which is why nothing is happening when you do this.

There are several solutions to your problem. If you are redirecting your user (after the form submission) back to the form page but with errors, you can include the "fragment identifier" in the url. Have the fragment identifier point to the ID of you form and the browser will automatically go to that part of the document. Example:

```
<form id="my-form">
    ...
</form>
```

And your url would be:

```
host/path?query=querystring#my-form
```

If you want to avoid having the page reload, try doing your validation in JS. The jQuery validation plugin is very easy to use and simply fantastic. See [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to find out how to use it. It's great because it does most of the heavy lifting for you and has a set of common, default validation methods.

Alternatively you can submit your form via ajax and return any validation errors that the server picks up. If you don't have any errors then you can redirect to the next page. If there are errors then stick them in the form or display an alert. This solution will avoid you having to replicate any complex validation logic on the client (if you want to use the jQuery validate plugin).

Comment: _"Returning false in the submit handler simply tells the browser not to bubble the event"_ - returning false cancels bubbling _and_ cancels the default action (where the default action is to submit).

Comment: @Jerry, which solution did you end up using?

Comment: @Simon. I am going to try your url fragment identifier first. I might have troubles doing ajax and JS ways since codeigniter handles many things for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use preventDefault() in jquery ..

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. but it will prevent my form to be submitted too. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using 'submit' form type (with #ajax callback) in jQuery dialogs on drupal forms:

try to use 'button' form type (also with #ajax callback).