# Prevent JQM causing page to scroll to top on form submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a webpage with a search at the bottom. I'm using JQuery Mobile to add touch navigation to my carousels on mobile, but it's also causing the page to scroll to top upon submitting the search form. It looks like it's trying to scroll to the form, but scrolls back to top when JQuery Mobile is loaded. I'd like to keep the user at the bottom of the page, or at least go back to the form after submission. What's the best way to not make this such a jarring experience for the user?

Below is the form and the js for it.

html -

```
  <form id="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="terms" data-role="none">
    <button id="submit" data-role="none" data-ajax="false"></button>
  </form>
  <div id="results">
  ...
  </div>
```

js -

```
$(function(){
  var searchParams    = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search),
      results_section = $("#search-results--section"),
      results         = results_section.find(".result"),
      index           = 0,
      input           = $("#terms"),
      availableTerms  = []; // store array to be used for autocomplete
    
    results.each(function(){
      var result    = $(this),
          shortname = result.data("shortname"),
          fullname  = result.data("fullname");
     
      
      if (searchParams.has("search")) {
        var search = searchParams.get("search").toLowerCase();

        if (shortname.indexOf(search) != -1 || fullname.indexOf(search) != -1) {
          result.show();
        } else {
          result.hide();
        }
        // set input's value to search query
        input.val(search);
      }
  });
  ...
});
```

I'm using JQM version 1.4.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent browser jump to top page when submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612569/prevent-browser-jump-to-top-page-when-submit-the-form)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you need to use the following:

1. Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the page from refreshing when you click 'submit'.
   see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
2. Use `window.location.pathname` with `history.pushState` to change the 'search' parameter in the URL without refreshing the page.
   see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

example (with jquery 3.5.1):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    url = window.location.pathname + '?searc=' + $('#terms').val();
    history.pushState({page: 1}, "title", url );
    alert(window.location.search);   
});
```